# How to get objects referenced by a program unit in JDAPI 11g Java Library?

Tags: java, oracle, forms, oracle11g

I am using Java JDAPI 11g library to parse an oracle forms in Java. 
I have noticed that in forms builder there is an option to directly get the list of objects referenced by a trigger or program unit as below.

[below a screenshot of the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thCzP.png)

I was wondering if this is possible to be done programatically using JDAPI, by reading some meta data or any other method.
(No detailed documentation found on the net :( )

Thank you in advance.